# Display problems with a two columns accordion menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

My code: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hwzpy/53/)

as you can see when you click on a parent link from one column the code moves the other column, and if you set the "position" propriety to "absolute" then the column will not moves but the red box at the bottom will doesn't move anymore...

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem by having your columns `float: left` rather than `display: inline-block`. Note that this'll require you to `clear` your floats at the bottom.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6c7s/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jh5np/16/

Comment: couple of problems with this: height is specified manually, without regards to the number of child items in a list (you could have avoided this by simply using `clear`. toggle makes no regard to whether the menu is being opened or closed. your solution works if you always click to open and click to close, but not if you click to move from one node to another. you could have solved this by passing a bool to the toggle function, or again, by using clear and no toggle at all.